# Exchanging pre-image of hash over a network securely

Tags: hash, key-exchange

Suppose A and B both have a secret value $S_a$ and $S_b$. A sends the hash of his secret $H(S_a)$ to B and B sends $H(S_b)$ to A.

At a later point in time, if both of them want to exchange their original secrets with each other. How do we ensure that the exchange happens atomically?